# Javascript Grab URL and insert into Pinterest button for Facebook Page Tab App

Tags: javascript, facebook, pinterest

I am trying to add a Pinterest button onto a product page for a single image in a Facebook Tab app.

The Pinterest code is grabbed from their goodies section, and must include a URL, the Media URL and the Description.

I am not that proficient with Javascript. I am trying to pull the URL and insert into the Javascript button for a single item. Please see below; Thanks.

```
    <a href="javascript:document.write(location.href);&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.net%2Ffiles%2Ftest%2Fks3.jpg&description=hello%20this%20is%20a%20product" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you trying to get Pinterest button working in Facebook Page tab this will not work due to inability to know which Page you're on in JavaScript.

This info is passed to server with `signed_request`. You have couple of options to do so:

- Build the link to page that will be linked to "Pin" server-side
- Pass information about Page and Page Tab to client side and build the link here.

Beware that this is just a link and it will not looks like Pin-It button until you including Pinterest JavaScript (`//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js`) on a page. If you build that link in Client Side you must include that JavaScript after, so link will be replaced by `iframe` with actual Pin-It button.